# Creating a vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

I have created a vue.js application by

```
vue init webpack myproject
```

I am then following a [link](https://morioh.com/p/06b7fc24c8b5), to create simple copper component, I have put that under src/components directory as follow:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<polygon-crop :imageSource = "'src/assets/logo.png'"
ref="canvas"> </polygon-crop>
<button @click.prevent="crop"> Crop </button>
<button @click.prevent="undo"> Undo </button>
<button @click.prevent="redo"> Redo </button>
<button @click.prevent="reset"> Reset </button>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import VuePolygonCropper from 'vue-polygon-cropper';
Vue.component(VuePolygonCropper);
export
default
{
    name: 'App',
    methods: {
        crop: function() {
            this.$refs.canvas.crop();
},
undo: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.undo();
},
redo: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.redo();
},
reset: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.reset();
}
}
};
</script>
```

But actually, it doesn't render properly and my component doesn't show up properly. I am new to vue.js and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you render the component?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get this component running with just this code snippet, there's a couple of things that you would need to do to fix this up.

Before we go any deeper, I would like you to make sure if you have installed this `vue-polygon-cropper` component. If you navigated to the package.json that is located in the same level as your "src" folder, you would see a mention of vue-polygon-cropper there, if not please install it by `npm install vue-polygon-croper` .

Let's take a look at your `<template>` section first:
1- In the template, you call a component `<polygon-crop>` but, there is no component registered by that name in your script (What you are attempting to register is 'VuePolygonCropper' so you should try using `<VuePolygonCropper>` component instead.

2-I see there you copied and pasted the logo image in assets, that's a great way to test it! However, Digging through the creator's example that they put up on github, It seems like this component requires a full path to your image file instead of the relative path. so instead of /src/assets/logo.png try doing `:imageSource="require('../assets/logo.png')"`
I'm assuming the assets logo is on a folder that is one level above your current component.
So your template should look like this:

```html
<template>
<div id="app">
<VuePolygonCropper :imageSource = "require('../assets/logo.png')"
ref="canvas"> </VuePolygonCropper>
<button @click.prevent="crop"> Crop </button>
<button @click.prevent="undo"> Undo </button>
<button @click.prevent="redo"> Redo </button>
<button @click.prevent="reset"> Reset </button>

</div>
</template>
```

Now on to your script!

just import the VuePolygonCropper and mention it as a component in the components section.
You don't need to import vue and do `Vue.component(VuePolygonCropper)`. The correct way to register this component would be like this

```js
<script>
import VuePolygonCropper from 'vue-polygon-cropper';
export
default
{
    name: 'App',
    components:{VuePolygonCropper},
    methods: {
        crop: function() {
            this.$refs.canvas.crop();
},
undo: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.undo();
},
redo: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.redo();
},
reset: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.reset();
}
}
};
</script>
```

For the heck of it, I have created [a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-kare-ihtqu?file=/src/App.vue) that you can play around with . You can try to play around with the App.vue file and see how it was created.

Happy coding!